# Detect when computer becomes active?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, mouseevent, osx-snow-leopard

I am having trouble finding an answer of how I could do this.

Basically what I want is to have a program start automatically when it detects that I am using the computer. So for example say I stop using the computer for a few hours and then come back, it would detect this and then open another program or something.

I am looking for a solution in Ruby/python/objective c/Applescript preferably. But anything would work.

I'd like it to work on Snow Leopard.

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: I found this which was very helpful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134901/mouse-tracking-daemon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor all events in the system using [`NSEvent addGlobalMonitor...`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSEvent/addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask%3ahandler%3a). Keep track of the time between two successive events, if it's over a treshold, it means the user was inactive for that time.